# In NetBeans IDE, is there a key combo to select up or down many lines?

Tags: ide, netbeans, editor, text-editor

I always run into this situation: cursor is on line 5 and I want to select everything down to line 16. I have to resort to shift-arrow, arrow, arrow, or use the mouse.

NetBeans has "go to line" (Control-G) but you can't hold down shift while doing that, so no good for selecting. There's also "bookmarks," but same problem.

Anyone know of a cool trick that solves this problem?

I'm open to alternate tool suggestions for OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Shift-PgDn or Shift-PgUp to select the next "page" of information.

The only thing that comes to mind is to create an editor macro.

Eg:

- Tools > Options > Editor > Macros
- Click "New" Enter a name:
- Enter a name for the macro: select-5-down
- For the macro code enter:

  selection-down
  selection-down
  selection-down
  selection-down
  selection-down
- Click "Set Shortcut" and assign a key binding. I used Alt-M.

Now each click of Alt-M extends the selection by 5 more lines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't seem to work on OS X. Different shortcut settings fail in different ways (e.g. enter exotic characters, do nothing at all). Appreciate the suggestion though.